# ConstraintLayout wraps only parts of contents

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I've a `ConstraintLayout` that wraps only parts of contents and I don't understand why.
Here below the graphical representation of my situation:

[image: Section of contents wrapped by my ConstraintLayout]

[image: View that isn't wrapped by my ConstraintLayout]

I want that my `mainConstraintLayout` wraps everything. If I change the `layout_height` of `mainConstraintLayout` from `wrap_content` to `match_parent` I get the following warning and it's still doesn't work:

> **ScrollView size validation**:
>   This androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout should use android:layout_height="wrap_content".
>   ScrollView children must set their layout_width or layout_height attributes to wrap_content rather than fill_parent or match_parent in the scrolling dimension  Issue id: ScrollViewSize

Anyone could help me? Thanks in advance.

**Update: xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".activities.EventActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/eventMainPicture"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/event_image_content_description"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/eventHeaderWrapper"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/event_placeholder_image" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/eventActionWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventHeaderWrapper">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/willPartecipateButton"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Inset"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryBlue"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_will_partecipate"
                    android:textColor="@color/primaryOrange"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/primaryOrange"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/primaryOrange"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/primaryOrange"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/interestedButton"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/interestedButton"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Inset"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryOrange"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_interested"
                    android:textColor="@color/primaryBlue"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/primaryOrange"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/primaryBlue"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/primaryBlue"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/willPartecipateButton"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/eventHeaderWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventMainPicture">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventCreatedBy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_createad_by"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventNamePlaceholder" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventCreatorName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_creator_placeholder"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eventCreatedBy"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventNamePlaceholder" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventNamePlaceholder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/event_name_placeholder"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="28sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/eventInfoWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventActionWrapper">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDateIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/calendar_icon" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/eventPositionIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventDateIcon"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/position_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_date"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/eventDateIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eventDateIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventPosition"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_place"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/eventPositionIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/eventPositionIcon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventDate" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/eventDescriptionWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventInfoWrapper">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDescriptionTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/event_description_title"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/eventDescription"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/event_description"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventDescriptionTitle" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/participantsWrapper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/participantsT"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/event_participants"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
        android:id="@+id/loadingView"
        style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.CubeGrid"
        android:layout_width="74dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:SpinKit_Color="@color/primaryOrange"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scrollView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: your xml, please

Comment: Posted @HoàngVũAnh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set wrong `constraint` to `participantsWrapper` View. You set top of `participantsWrapper` at bottom of `mainConstraintLayout`. So, naturally it goes beyond `mainConstraintLayout`. Try to

Use

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/eventDescriptionWrapper"
```

Instead of

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Comment: I've got the bad habit to use only graphical editor and the constraint seemed right

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change the layout's height to include everything, you just have to make sure that all views are direct children of the constraint layout. Essentially place all the views that you want within the tags: `<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> ...</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`

You might want to consider flattening that layout as well. Make Scrollview the parent layout and make it to match_parent, and then put everything in a single constraint layout and make it's height to wrap_content so that you don't mess up the scrolling.

Comment: All of my views are already direct children of a ConstraintLayout

Comment: @pairon it's easy to mess up your constraints when you nest so many layouts within one another. Yes, you have an outer constraint layout, but also many others within it. The idea of a Constraint Layout is to have a flat way of organising all your views.